# How to enforce code contract on a Pony Entity

Tags: python-3.x, separation-of-concerns, ponyorm

I am aiming at separating concerns using layered architecture in my design. In order to achieve that I define core object properties using Abstract Base Classes (ABC), eg.:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class AbstractPerson(ABC):

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def name(self):
        pass
```

which I then use in the application layer:

```
class Person(AbstractPerson):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
```

The persistence layer should be separated from the application, so I define Pony-classes:

```
from pony import orm

def define_pony_person(database):

    class PonyPerson(database.Entity, AbstractPerson):

        name = orm.Required(
            str,
            unique=True
        )

    return PonyPerson
```

Inheriting from AbstractPerson is meant to enforce the Person-contract through layers. Than in the client code (e.g. business logic) I could instantiate and use my core object:

```
person = Person(
    name='Foo'
)
```

and in some other part of the code (e.g. in a Repository) I would persist it:

```
db = orm.Database()
PonyPerson = define_pony_person(db)
db.bind('sqlite', ':memory:')
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)
pony_person = PonyPerson(
    name=person.name
)
```

But when I try to do it like that, it turns out that a Pony Entity doesn't mix with an ABC smoothly:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 43, in <module>
    define_pony_person(db)
  File "./test.py", line 28, in define_pony_person
    class PonyPerson(database.Entity, AbstractPerson):
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

Is there a way to enforce my core object contract on a Pony Entity along the lines sketched above?